# submit button not getting invoked - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple controls, in which I have set the required field validation. If the data is correct, i want to invoke the submit button. But even when all data are filled, and clicking on submit button, the button is not getting invoked. Below is the sample code used:

```
  <form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">

  <div class="container" ng-show="createMenu">
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <label>Test:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <select name="testTypeSelect" required ng-model="selectedtestType" ng-options="test.TestTypeName for test in tests" ng-change="updateImageUrl(selectedTestType)">
                            <option value="">-- Select the test --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.testTypeSelect.$error.required"> Type is required</span>

                <div class="row">
                    <div >
                        <label>Name :</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" required ng-model="testName" name="testName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
```

// In controller.js

```
 $scope.add = function () {

        $scope.init();   

        alert("hi");
            $scope.addData();

    };
```

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: may be the form is invalid. You made a condition, try to remove mainForm.$valid in ng-submit of form tag. If you want the form to be valid, enter alid data

Comment: Use the Angular inspector to look at the $valid attribute of the form

Comment: can u add plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

your controller is inject after form tag, add() function call is out of controller inject.

```
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
```

change to

```
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
```

Comment: Tried that.. same issue exists